# Optimize writing multiple CSV files from lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, optimization

I want to create one CSV per list using csv module. My code works but it feels a little silly writing the same lines again and again. I was wondering if there is a better, efficient way to code this part.

My spreadsheet has a total of 3 sheets. row1 has the sheet1 data in a list, row2 has the sheet2 data in a list and so on.

```
  with open("sheet1.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows1)

  with open("sheet2.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows2)

  with open("sheet3.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows3)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iterate on a list of tuples for instance.

```
for f,rows in [("sheet1.csv",rows1),("sheet2.csv",rows2),("sheet3.csv",rows3)]:
    with open(f, "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

note that it would be even simpler to put your `rowsX` variables in a list of rows and generate sheet names using `enumerate` and `format` if they're as you described or use `zip` on both lists if names cannot be easily generated.

```
row_list = [rows1,rows2,rows3]
name_list = ["apple.csv","banana.csv","orange.csv"]
for name,rows in zip(name_list,row_list):
    with open("sheet{}.csv".format(i), "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

also note: `with open(f, "wb") as f:` is only for python 2 csv writer.

For python 3, do: `with open(f, "w", newline="") as f:`

Comment: Wow thank you! This definitely looks cleaner. How would you use the second method if each sheet has a distinct name? So instead of being sheet1.csv, sheet2.csv and sheet3.csv, they would be apple.csv, banana.csv and strawberry.csv.